# Cannot create DB Table, which is the same as the first DB I have (I cloned and changed names)

Tags: android, database, sqlite

In my Android program, I need **3 DB's** or **3 DB Tables in 1 DB**. First will have some data's. Second will have passwords. I was creating the second one. **The first one is compiling without problems** but the second one gives me some errors and for last 10 hours, I couldn't fix it. (**I cloned the first DB table**, paste to the second and changed variables, names, etc. **I controlled few times, there is no syntax error?**)
*NOTE: I'm very new to develop a proper login process. This is my homework, prof doesn't expect me giving him a proper login process so I don't need security or etc. Just password is correct or not. Login is OK or not.*

Some help will be great, as I said, I have wasted my 10 hours....

## DataBase Adapter

```
package com.example.tsfc;

import java.io.IOException;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBLogin {

public static final String  KEY_SELECT = "select";

private static final String TAG = "DBLogin";


private static final String     DATABASE_NAME = "DBLog";
private static final String     DATABASE_TABLE = "log";
private static final int    DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table if not exists log (" +
        "select string not null " + 
        ");";


private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBLogin(Context ctx){

    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    DatabaseHelper(Context context){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        try{
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }
        catch(SQLException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}


public DBLogin open() throws SQLException{

    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    DBHelper.close();
}

public long insertRecord(String select){

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_SELECT, select);


    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);


}

 public Cursor getAllRecords() 
    {
        return db.query(false, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_SELECT}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws IOException {

     Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_SELECT}, 
                null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

}

public boolean updateRecord(long rowID, String select){

    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_SELECT, select);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, null, null) > 0;
}
public String[] displayRecord(Cursor cr)
{
     String array[] = {cr.getString(0), cr.getString(1), cr.getString(2), cr.getString(3), cr.getString(4), cr.getString(5)};

     return array; 
    } 
}
```

## Creating DB in main.java

```
package com.example.tsfc;
//some imports.....

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button userButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.user_button);
    userButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowMessagesPage.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    try {           
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/DBMessages";
        File f = new File(destPath);            
        if (!f.exists()) {          
            CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("meee"), 
                new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Button loginButton =(Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginPage.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    try {           
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/DBLog";
        File f = new File(destPath);            
        if (!f.exists()) {          
            CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("meeemeeee"), 
                new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
throws IOException {
    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}






boolean checkConnection(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;


    }
    else {
        return false;
    }


}


public void sendMessage(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowMessagesPage.class);

    if (checkConnection()){
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    else {Toast.makeText(this, "There is no internet connection. Please check and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return;
    }   
}

public void login(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginPage.class);


    if (checkConnection()){
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
    else {Toast.makeText(this, "There is no internet connection. Please check and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return;
}   
}}
```

## Working on DB

```
public class LoginPage extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_page);

        Button loginButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                isOK();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }});}



    public String sman;
    public String sdev;
    public String spass;
    public String sor;


    boolean checkConnection(){
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;


        }
        else {
            return false;
        }


    }


private void isOK() throws IOException{ 
    DBLogin db = new DBLogin(this);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


EditText passEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
spass = passEditText.getText().toString();

String sor = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();




db.open();        
long id = db.insertRecord("asdasd123");
id = db.insertRecord("qweqwe123");

db.close();

if (spass.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "You have entered something wrong. Please check.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 return;}
 else {
     if(checkConnection()){
         Log.d("test", "adding");
         db.open();
         Cursor cr = db.getRecord(1);
         Cursor cr2 = db.getRecord(2);

         if(spass == cr.toString() && sor == "Manager") {
             Toast.makeText(this,"Password confirmed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Intent i = new Intent(this, ManagerView.class);
             startActivity(i);}
         else if (spass == cr2.toString() && sor == "Developer"){
             Toast.makeText(this,"Password confirmed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             Intent a = new Intent(this, DeveloperView.class);
             startActivity(a);}
         else {
             Toast.makeText(this,"Password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
         }
         db.close();
         return;}
     else {Toast.makeText(this, "There is no internet connection. Please check and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return;
        }   
 }}}
```

## LOGCAT

```
12-30 10:53:45.871: E/SQLiteLog(907): (1) near "select": syntax error
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907): Error inserting select=asdasd123
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "select": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO log(select) VALUES (?)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.DBLogin.insertRecord(DBLogin.java:82)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage.error(LoginPage.java:77)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage.access$0(LoginPage.java:63)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage$1.onClick(LoginPage.java:31)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:45.901: E/SQLiteLog(907): (1) near "select": syntax error
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907): Error inserting select=qweqwe123
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "select": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO log(select) VALUES (?)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.DBLogin.insertRecord(DBLogin.java:82)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage.error(LoginPage.java:78)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage.access$0(LoginPage.java:63)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage$1.onClick(LoginPage.java:31)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-30 10:53:45.950: E/SQLiteDatabase(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:45.960: D/test(907): adding
12-30 10:53:45.990: E/SQLiteLog(907): (1) near "select": syntax error
12-30 10:53:45.990: D/AndroidRuntime(907): Shutting down VM
12-30 10:53:45.990: W/dalvikvm(907): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "select": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT select FROM log
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1073)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.example.tsfc.DBLogin.getRecord(DBLogin.java:95)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage.error(LoginPage.java:89)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage.access$0(LoginPage.java:63)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.example.tsfc.LoginPage$1.onClick(LoginPage.java:31)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-30 10:53:46.010: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I have tried clearing the emulator cache, uninstalling the app from emulator, using another emulator. All failed.

Comment: Don't mention that we should do your homework, people don't like this. Also your column has the name 'select' which is not good, rename it to something else.

Comment: @vorrtex: Did I say do my homework? I just explained why my login process is too simple because, thought someone can say "your login process is not good" or something like that. I didn't want to argue about that....   I have tried "select","or","asd" "qwe","change","title" and "pass" column names. Also I have had one more column: "id" but erased it. Nothing changed.

Comment: @vorrtex: Also, we don't have to use database. We have not take class about databases yet, prof doesn't expect database. I can use a simple file input output stream. This is not about my HW. We call this desire to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` is an SQL keyword.
You can either rename this column to have a name that is not a keyword (and will not become one in future versions of the DB), or use double quotes to force it to be interpreted as an identifier: `"select"`.

Comment: I have tried "select","or","asd" "qwe","change","title" and "pass" column names. Also I have had one more column: "id" but erased it. Nothing had changed. But now I tried again and it's OK now... Maybe, I did a mistake somewhere else... anyway. I have a another problem now..   Look at Working on DB. I inserted a password "asdasd123", and  tested equality between this password and the password I entered.. There is a problem, app says password is invalid. :/

Comment: **Cursor cr = db.getRecord(1); Cursor cr2 = db.getRecord(2);**  Making 1 to 0, 2 to 1 is not working...

Comment: OK. I solved the problem... While checking the equality between strings, I used .equal() and it's ok now.